# Update a unique Vue Model in a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I generate a list, edit some data, and push then it to db? When I hit 'submit', the changes made have no effect.

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/cf0cuz0d/)

```
<div id="demo">
<button v-on="click: generateProducts">Generate products</button>
<table border='1px'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product name</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            <td>
                <input name="productQty[]" type="text" value="{{ product.qty }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
new Vue({

el: '#demo',

data: {
    products: []
},

methods: {
    generateProducts: function() {
        console.log('works');
        var self = this;

        self.products = [
            {name: 'Black Box', qty: '40'},
            {name: 'Blue Box', qty: '40'},
            {name: 'Orange Box', qty: '40'}
        ];
    }
}
});
```

Comment: When you submit what? I don't see a submit button let alone a form anywhere.

Comment: Sorry. I thought that a complete form was not necessary.  So, I'm using Laravel to backend, and when I send data that was generated after pressed "generate products", changes that I made in ProductQty, has no effect. In other word, still show qty:40.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `<input v-model="product.qty" type="text" />`

That should do the Trick.